# Create a stored procedure that runs a SELECT statement to keep an Oracle table updated

Tags: sql, oracle

In order to optimize a .NET application I created a custom table on an Oracle DB to avoid costly JOINs every time the application queried the DB. The below SQL was used to initially populate this custom table. As the tables used to populate the custom table are constantly changing I need to ensure that my custom table is kept up to date. I believe I need to create a stored procedure that runs on a predetermined frequency that will do the following: a) remove any records that no longer exist in the recordset returned by the SELECT b) append any records that exist in the recordset returned by the SELECT but do not exist in the QL_ASSETS table and c) update any data in records that exist in both the QL_ASSETS table and the recordset returned by the SELECT that differ. Would a simple UPDATE query accomplish this or does that just update data in records that exist in both the QL_ASSETS table and the recordset returned by the SELECT that differ? If the latter, any suggestions as to how I can accomplish all 3 tasks? Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO QL_ASSETS (
   THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN,
   LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
   LOCATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   PLI_NAME,
   PLI,
   STREET,
   CITY,
   STATE,
   ZIPCODE,
   COUNTRY,
   ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID,
   PARENT_ID,
   LOCATION_STREET,
   LOCATION_CITY,
   LOCATION_STATE,
   LOCATION_ZIPCODE,
   LOCATION_COUNTRY,       
   ULTIMATE_PARENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER)            
(SELECT 
   B.THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN,
   A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
   D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS LOCATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   F.NAME AS PLI_NAME,
   A.PLI,
   H.STREET,
   H.CITY,
   H.STATE,
   H.ZIPCODE,
   H.COUNTRY,
   D.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID,
   D.PARENT_ID,
   G.STREET AS LOCATION_STREET,
   G.CITY AS LOCATION_CITY,
   G.STATE AS LOCATION_STATE,
   G.ZIPCODE AS LOCATION_ZIPCODE,
   G.COUNTRY AS LOCATION_COUNTRY,       
   E.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS ULTIMATE_PARENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM ASSET_PLUS A,
 QUARTERLY_LETTER_LOAD B,
 DATASTORE_PLI_MAPPING C,
 ACCOUNT D,
 ACCOUNT E,
 PROD_INT F,
 ADDRESS G,
 ADDRESS H 
WHERE B.THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN = C.DATASTORE_SVC_NAME 
AND C.PLI = A.PLI 
AND A.PRODUCT_ID = F.ROW_ID 
AND E.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID = H.ADDRESS_ID 
AND D.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID = G.ADDRESS_ID 
AND D.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID = E.ACCOUNT_ID 
AND D.ACCOUNT_ID = A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: Hope materialized views help you!

Comment: how frequently will the underlying data change? Materialized views are something like a snapshot of your select query result, which you can ask oracle to update in specified interval. There're some downside of it, if your table data receives frequent modifications

Comment: The underlying data changes daily so I would want the refresh to be done on the same frequency.

Comment: In such case a simple [RESULT CACHE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15857/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA616) may help already. In this case only the first execution takes a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `materialised view` is available immediately after creation and will be refreshed daily, as per the time frame you mentioned (`START WITH`....).

You can also **refresh it manually** like

```
EXEC DBMS_REFRESH.REFRESH(name => 'YOUR_MAT_VIEW');
```

**And the DDL for the MV:**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW YOUR_MAT_VIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH TRUNC(SYSDATE)--(+?/24) ?- HOUR OF DAY
NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1--(+?/24)
SELECT 
   B.THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN,
   A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID,
   D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS LOCATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   F.NAME AS PLI_NAME,
   A.PLI,
   H.STREET,
   H.CITY,
   H.STATE,
   H.ZIPCODE,
   H.COUNTRY,
   D.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID,
   D.PARENT_ID,
   G.STREET AS LOCATION_STREET,
   G.CITY AS LOCATION_CITY,
   G.STATE AS LOCATION_STATE,
   G.ZIPCODE AS LOCATION_ZIPCODE,
   G.COUNTRY AS LOCATION_COUNTRY,       
   E.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS ULTIMATE_PARENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM ASSET_PLUS A,
 QUARTERLY_LETTER_LOAD B,
 DATASTORE_PLI_MAPPING C,
 ACCOUNT D,
 ACCOUNT E,
 PROD_INT F,
 ADDRESS G,
 ADDRESS H 
WHERE B.THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE_CLEAN = C.DATASTORE_SVC_NAME 
AND C.PLI = A.PLI 
AND A.PRODUCT_ID = F.ROW_ID 
AND E.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID = H.ADDRESS_ID 
AND D.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID = G.ADDRESS_ID 
AND D.ULTIMATE_PARENT_ID = E.ACCOUNT_ID 
AND D.ACCOUNT_ID = A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID;
```

You can further query from the YOUR_MAT_VIEW like as a normal simple table.

Comment: Thanks Maheswaran. One question: I don't see any reference to the table I want refreshed in the MV DLL; how does the MV know which table to refresh?

Comment: MV doesn't go with just one table, refreshing means, in simple words, It runs the query and populates it view with new data.. So it is not table based, but query based.. in this situation

Comment: This MV works on `REFRESH COMPLETE`, it's also possible to create a MV with `FAST REFRESH`. This type is much quicker since it only updates the changed records instead of entire delete and insert. In such case you can refresh the MV even after every COMMIT on the database. For fast refresh you have to create `Materialized View Log` on base tables.

Comment: @Wernfried yes, it goes with his requirements and criticality. To choose between `COMPLETE` and `FAST REFRESH`. I just tried to keep it simple, as it is once a day

Comment: Got it, thanks Maheswaran. Can an index be added to the material view as well?

Comment: Yes, you can create indexes on MV. but please make sure, you drop the index, do the refresh , and recreate.. probably using a script. on a daily basis. Try in any test environment, and consult with DBA on the impact.

Comment: This is new for me, according my knowledge the index on MV has no difference to an index on a table